# Xcode git merge - no branches found

Tags: xcode, git, git-merge

Within Xcode 6.4, I'm trying to merge a branch back to master on a remote and Xcode displays no branches at all when using any "Merge from Branch" or "Merge into Branch" menu option.

When I check out a fresh copy from the remote, two branches are clearly seen on the remote.  Master and the one I am working in.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Have you actually checked out both branches?  Or are you talking about a remote branch like `refs/remotes/origin/some-remote-branch`.  You need both branches to be checked out locally before a typical merge.

Comment: Thanks Wolf.  I wasn't sure if I needed both checked out locally, but they are now and still, no branches are displayed when I try to merge.

Comment: What happens when you use the command line tools from within your working copy?  What does `git status` say?  What does `git branch` say?  What happens when you say `git checkout master ; git merge my-branch`?

Comment: I'm asking so we can figure out if the problem is in Xcode, or Git, or your working copy.

Comment: Thanks.  git status states `On branch It2
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/It2'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`.  git branch states `* It2`.  git checkout master states that `files will be overwritten` - basically these files are files that I want to ignore - UserInterfaceState.xcusserstate, breakpoints and .ds_store.  git merge it2 states `Already up-to-date.`

Comment: Alright.  So it seems like a bug in Xcode that it's not showing you the branches you just proved you had.  Do I understand you correctly that you didn't end up checking out `master`?  So you weren't on `master` when you asked to `git merge It2`?  If so, `Already up-to-date.` makes sense.  You have files in the way of checking out `master`, so either move them aside (if you want to save them), or `checkout -f master` (if you're ok with overwriting them).  Then let's try the merge again and see what happens: `git merge It2`.

Comment: I think I do - a little so far.  I do have one branch now on my desktop that shows both `master` and `it2`, both checked out within the past 5 mins.  The only remaining files in question are 1 modified `xcshareddata/XXXX.xccheckout` and 2 untracked schemes that are not in the shared data.  So, I'm looking into how to properly resolve these.